# Xmlport CSV import only field with value <> NULL

Tags: csv, import, dynamics-nav

I'm trying to import CSV file to update record but skip the field in CSV with NULL value, is there any way to do this? At the moment the null value is overwriting my table's record's value. Anyone can help?
Below is my CSV. The first two value is Primary Keys.

```
No.,Code,StartDate,EndDate,FCode
P18010001,PCT0001,2018/4/7,,GV000
P18010001,PCT0001,,2018/4/9,GV000
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the INSERTs and MODIFYs manually:

Set the `AutoSave` property to `No` on the DataItem.

In the `OnBeforeInsertRecord` [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/onbeforeinsertrecord-trigger) just call INSERT(TRUE) on the DataItem-record.

In the `OnBeforeModifyRecord` [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/onbeforemodifyrecord-trigger) first GET the record in a separate variable, apply the new values (for the dates: only if they're `<> 0D`). Then MODIFY(TRUE) the separate variable.